# iOS Auto-Layout: Dynamic height for table view cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, row-height

I have a table view with a bunch of cells (custom cell, which only has its content view).

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I'm adding a predefined UIView (which has several subviews) to the content view of the custom cell. I set up all constraints for the UIView and its subviews before.

Last but not least, I set the vertical and horizontal constraints for the content view of my custom cell (superview) and the UIView, which was added before (subview).

The constraint strings look like this:

```
    H:|[view]|
    V:|[view]|
```

Unfortunately, I still get the default height for all table view cells. I'm wondering If there's a way to let auto layout do the calculation of the height automatically according to content size.

Comment: No.  You need to implement `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` and return a height or the default height of the cell will be used.

Comment: Is there any way to let the the view decide which height it should get?

Comment: If you use custom `UITableViewCells` you could create a method in the subclass that returns the height for that cell and then call that method in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath`. Obviously, try to make the calculation fast and efficient (possibly pre-calculate the result on any change and cache the result if the calculation is very complex).

Comment: thanks for your answer. unfortunately calculating the cells content is no solution for me. the problem is, that i don't know what's inside the view.

Comment: I don't know your app but at some point you must load content to it's view.  Perhaps if you ask a new question that details exactly how the view works then someone can find a method for calculating the content height (text obviously has a height so does graphics - I can't imagine what you're loading that doesn't have a known or calculable height).

Comment: But that's the big advantage of auto layout. Even a scroll view and its content can be layouted automatically without knowing which size any subview is. Of course I could calculate and sum up the heights of my subviews - but this seems to be the alternative to the whole auto-layout thing, and mixing up both approaches is a bit dirty.

Comment: Maybe in a future iOS version they'll update the way tableview cells work but (as of iOS 6) you need to mix both approaches. Good luck with the app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic table cell height with Autolayout iOS 6 +](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562859/dynamic-table-cell-height-with-autolayout-ios-6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using `CGSize size = [view systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];` in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 5):

Check out my detailed answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/796419

It takes a bit of work to set up, but you can absolutely have Auto Layout constraints driving a completely dynamic table view without a single hardcoded height (and let the constraint solver do the heavy lifting and provide you with the row height).

Answer (score 2):

Auto Layout won't help with the cell height. You'll need to set that in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath`. I guess you're probably asking this because your cell heights are variable, not fixed. i.e., they depend on the content.

To resolve that, pre-calculate the cell heights and store them in an array. Return the value for the appropriate `indexPath` in the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Be sure to calculate content sizes on the main thread, using `sizeThatFits` of `UILabel` classes and such like.

If your calculation is intensive, do the majority of it off `main` apart from the view related  methods such as `sizeThatFits`.

Answer (score 0):

To set automatic dimensions for row height, ensure following steps to make, auto dimension effective for cell/row height layout.

- Assign and implement dataSource and delegate
- Assign `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to rowHeight & estimatedRowHeight
- Implement delegate/dataSource methods (i.e. `heightForRowAt` and return a value `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to it)

**Swift:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Don't forget to set dataSource and delegate for table
    table.dataSource = self
    table.delegate = self

    // Set automatic dimensions for row height
    // Swift 4.2 onwards
    table.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    table.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension


    // Swift 4.1 and below
    table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    table.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}



// UITableViewAutomaticDimension calculates height of label contents/text
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // Swift 4.2 onwards
    return UITableView.automaticDimension

    // Swift 4.1 and below
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

For label instance in UITableviewCell

- Set number of lines = 0 (& line break mode = truncate tail)
- Set all constraints (top, bottom, right left) with respect to its superview/ cell container.
- *Optional*: Set minimum height for label, if you want minimum vertical area covered by label, even if there is no data.

[image]